# Duplicate Symbol Error in Objective-C build?

Tags: ios, objective-c, duplicate-symbol

I got this error when I press build+debug:

```
ld: duplicate symbol .objc_class_name_BlogTableItemCell in /Users/fabian/Development/Workspaces/iphone_experiments/xcode_build_output/MausLog.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MausLog.build/Objects-normal/i386/BlogTableItemCell-3733583914888A7B.o and /Users/fabian/Development/Workspaces/iphone_experiments/xcode_build_output/MausLog.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MausLog.build/Objects-normal/i386/BlogTableItemCell-3733583914888A7B.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Do not make the @implementation part inside the .h file.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It seems that you are compiling the same BlogTableItemCell class two times in different places of your code. This may happen in the following cases.

- You have put the same class
  implementation into two different
  files;
- You actually have just one
  implementation of this class, however
  you are also linking in your project a framework
  or library containing a class whose
  name is exactly the same of yours.

Try finding in the whole project your class and make sure only one copy is available within your project.

Comment: 1.You have put the same class implementation into two different files;
-> I checked that with "Find in Project". There is only one file!

2. "linking in your project a framework or library containing a class whose name is exactly the same of yours."
-> I also checked that with  "Find in Project". There is only one link at the right position.

Any suggest how to go from here?

Comment: Alright i got it. Xcode had an old reference to the file in the class explorer. Thanks

Comment: I had this same problem when I integrated the Facebook SDK (which included SBJson files) into a project I was using that already had those same SBJson classes. Having two copies was causing the error. Finally, I deleted one set of those files and then the problem was resolved.

Comment: Just ran into this error ... I was importing "*.m" instead "*.h" files in one of my implementations!

Comment: I run into this problem when I make it both in the target and in the test.

Comment: Copy-pasting a class...I forgot to change the implementation name :-O

Comment: thanks @ChristophH. !  this is a very common error it seems

Answer (score 177):

You could also get this error if you mistakenly let Xcode's auto-complete for #import statements specify the '.m" file for the 'duplicate' class instead of the '.h'.

Comment: One of the best catches ever!

Comment: I wish there was some way to change THIS answer to the accepted answer.

Comment: Excellent.  This just happened to me and my heart stopped beating for a moment.

Answer (score 43):

For me, changing 'No Common Blocks' from Yes to No ( under Targets->Build Settings->Apple LLVM - Code Generation )
[image]

Comment: Brad: you saved me the day !!

Comment: Wow that was exactly what happening to me. Thanks

Comment: You're a rock star.

Comment: this must be a solution but in my case I'm using an 3rd party application, it internally using same framework file which I'm using in my project. Any solution you can refer ?

Answer (score 25):

I had a similar problem due to poor defining of consts.
I had defined a const in my header:

```
int const kCropLocationTop = 1;
```

This was presumably imported multiple times. To fix i changed the header def as follows:

```
extern int const kCropLocationTop;
```

and moved the assigning of the const to the .m file:

```
int const kCropLocationTop = 1;
```

Hope that helps anyone who's as ignorant of simple objective c concepts as I am!

Answer (score 18):

[iPhone: Duplicate Symbol Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264455/iphone-duplicate-symbol-error/5773064#5773064) by user576924

answered it correctly for me. However to find the offending gremlin this ZSH snippet.

```
grep "import.*\.m" **/*.[hm]
```

Will immediately tell you where your error is.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think it can be summed up as: Don't try to `#import` .m files!

Comment: Could perform a similar search in Xcode. Search the whole project (Command-Shift-F) for `.m"` and `.m>`. Both should be sufficient to find the offending line.

Answer (score 18):

By mistake the source file was included twice in the Project -> Build Phase -> Compile Sources. Removing one of them solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.  Lots of people here said the issue was things being added twice, but didn't explain how to remove it.

Comment: Same problem for me. This happened following a svn merge and resolving conflicts in the project.pbxproj

Comment: THIS. How come this answer has only 9 upvotes? Seems like it's the only cause I ever run into when I get linker errors. I would like to upvote this 10 times.

Comment: Bad auto merge from git caused a dup in my project file.  Another dev had renamed a bunch of files.  To fix it I had to remove both copies and re-add a single copy.

Comment: Thanks !! you saved my day (y)

Answer (score 9):

The most common reason for this error is importing an xyz.m file instead of the xyz.h file.
Check if your imports contain something like
  `#import "----.m"`

Answer (score 4):

Just to add; Using Xcode to generate subclassed managed objects (Core Data) can sometimes duplicate the generated files. For me the fix was to delete the generated files and re-generate them.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem myself. For the list, here's another possibility:

Duplicated linking line in the project file.

I caused this merging conflicts on a SVN update, when I accidentally duplicated a line.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me, too.  In my case, one (just one) of my core data automatically generated classes was inserted twice.  I spotted the duplication by looking at Build Phases...Compile Sources. Simply deleting one of the occurrences solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding another possible cause to the list... you may have mistakingly created multiple constants in the implementation file, but outside of the implementation, with the same name.

In HeaderFileOne.m

```
NSString * const kCoolConstant = @"cool";
```

In HeaderFileTwo.m

```
NSString * const kCoolConstant = @"cool";
```

So changing one of those constant names would fix the compile error.

Answer (score 2):

This may help someone

I got this error because I duplicate a ViewController and then renamed it. So when I compile I got this error. The reason was in both of the view controllers there was a "float" variable with same name i.e "float padding=10.0" which I had defined on class level.
Renaming the name of the above mentioned variable in One of the view controllers solved my problem.

Comment: I have the same situation - my question is: why is this a problem? Surely two classes can have the same internal variable name...

Answer (score 1):

I also faced to this problem. My solution was rename one of global variable, which has the same name as one in other class. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me while I was playing with localizable xib files, accidentally I have created two implementation files and appereantly that caused the problem in my case. After deleting / recreating the implementation file without doing the same mistake, the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One of our developers left the "libSoomla*" project files in there twice. I removed the duplicate soomla files, re-built, and that fixed it!

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In may case, I followed some instructions to build a newer version of Subversion which directed me to create this symbolic link:

```
ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain
```

Now I'm really a Windows guy so it wasn't immediately obvious to me - but removing the link fixed it for me (after restarting XCode):

```
rm /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain
```

Phew.

(The actual error I got was the one described here:
[build error duplicate symbols arclite.o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531958/build-error-duplicate-symbols-arclite-o))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you didn't import .m File . For me this happen I added #import "SchoolCommuterHome.m" instead of #import "SchoolCommuterHome.h"