# How to solve the error while adding new classes

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate Symbol Error in Objective-C build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264455/iphone-duplicate-symbol-error)

What I did is creating two different iPhone applications individually, now what I need is I have to combine these two applications as single application by using tabbar controller.But while adding the second application classes to first classes it shows the error:

> Command
>      /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>      failed with exit code 1

---

I can't understand what is it and one more is shown as:

- `Duplicate Symbol _count in

  /users/ensisinfosolutionscom/Desktop/abc/build/CustomImagePicker.build
  /Debug-iphonesimulator/CustomImagePicker.build/Objects-normal/i386/numbers.o
  and
  /users/ensisinfosolutionscom/Desktop/abc/build/CustomImagePicker.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CustomImagePicker.o`

---

here customimagepicker is my class name. What is this error?

Comment: Sometimes searching helps, your question is answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264455/iphone-duplicate-symbol-error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264455/iphone-duplicate-symbol-error)

Answer (score -1):

This looks like you are lacking some library