# Clash facebook-json with existing JSON library in project

Tags: iphone, json, facebook

I want to use the Facebook authentication in my iphone app. But the problem is that I am already using this json library. https://github.com/stig/json-framework

After copying `FBConnect` to my project, there is a linker error, saying that there is a clash around a class named `SBJsonParser`.

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJsonParser in
>   /Users/saileshmittal/Library/Developer/Xcode/.../i386/SBJsonParser-5856452AC92B115F.o
>   for architecture i386

I don't want to change the existing code around the json library that I am using. Is there a work around for this?

I may be looking at the namespacing in importing, something like `import "myProject/json.h"` and `import "facebook/json.h"`; how do I go about changing the project structure to support this? Or if there is a better solution, please tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is using the same JSON library, so the easiest thing would probably be to remove one of the two libraries from your project. If you want to keep your own, then just remove Facebook's JSON classes instead.

Comment: Removing one din't help much. I think the JSON in facebook is outdated(?)

Comment: Marking as correct since it partially solved my problem :). Though I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130568/issues-when-installing-th-json-framework-on-xcode4

Comment: As a principle I must disagree, and now that the Facebook iOS SDK is a library and no longer open code, you may find this an even bigger problem