# MonoTouch - Conflict between 2 binding Projects

Tags: c#, objective-c, binding, xamarin.ios

I'm wanting to use two Objective-C libraries in a MonoTouch app: the Facebook library and an ad library from Millennial Media.

When I try to compile my MonoTouch app (even just for the simulator), I get the error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SBJsonParser in /var/folders/4s/lcvdj54x0g72nrsw9vzq6nm80000gn/T/tmp6024c613.tmp/libMMSDK_4.5.5.a(SBJsonParser.o) and /var/folders/4s/lcvdj54x0g72nrsw9vzq6nm80000gn/T/tmp6024c613.tmp/libFacebookSDK.a(SBJsonParser.o) for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I assume both libraries are using `SBJsonParser` and that's the issue.

So then I tried putting them in the same MonoTouch binding project, but still got the exact same error.

My bindings came from [the Xamarin binding projects on GitHub](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings).  Here is what linker flags are setup:

```
[assembly: LinkWith ("libMMSDK_4.5.5.a", LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator, Frameworks = "CoreGraphics QuartzCore MediaPlayer CoreLocation MobileCoreServices AudioToolbox AVFoundation SystemConfiguration UIKit", ForceLoad = true)]

...

[assembly: LinkWith ("libFacebookSDK.a", LinkTarget.Simulator | LinkTarget.ArmV6 | LinkTarget.ArmV7, ForceLoad = true, Frameworks = "CoreGraphics")]
```

Is there something I can do to fix this?  Maybe an extra MonoTouch compiler flag?

Comment: Some clues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130568/issues-when-installing-th-json-framework-on-xcode4  Can this be fixed on the MonoTouch side?  Or will I have to recompile XCode projects here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found a workaround.

The Millenial Media SDK, had a folder named `MMSDK_Split_Libraries`, peeking inside I found a `libMMSDK_4.5.5_withoutJSON.a` file, complete with `SBJsonParser` implementation files for XCode.  Using this different library, at least my app compiles now.  I haven't integrated the MM SDK yet, so I will have to see if it works properly or not.

Curious to see if someone out there has another way to fix it.

Comment: MM SDK seems to work fine, it must be using `SBJsonParser` from the Facebook SDK.  Kind of crazy, but glad it worked out.