# Build Error: ld: Duplicate Symbol _canVirate

Tags: ios, build, compiler-warnings, duplicate-symbol

Below is my build log. I've tried all the usual error-fixing solutions: Deleting build folder, cleaning, restarting Xcode, etc.

> Ld
>   build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SquirrelGame.app/SquirrelGame
>   normal i386 cd
>   /Users/Student/Desktop/SquirrelGame
>   setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>   setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/Student/Desktop/SquirrelGame/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/Student/Desktop/SquirrelGame/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/Student/Desktop/SquirrelGame -filelist /Users/Student/Desktop/SquirrelGame/build/SquirrelGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SquirrelGame.build/Objects-normal/i386/SquirrelGame.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -all_load -ObjC -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -weak_framework Foundation -weak_framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox
>   -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -weak_framework MapKit
>   -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework
>   SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3.0
>   -framework MediaPlayer -framework AVFoundation -framework MessageUI
>   -framework MobileCoreServices -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -weak_framework GameKit
>   -lz.1.2.3 -framework OpenFeint -o /Users/Student/Desktop/SquirrelGame/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SquirrelGame.app/SquirrelGame
>
> ld: duplicate symbol _canVirate in
>   /Users/Student/Desktop/SquirrelGame/build/SquirrelGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SquirrelGame.build/Objects-normal/i386/SquirrelGameViewController.o
>   and
>   /Users/Student/Desktop/SquirrelGame/build/SquirrelGame.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SquirrelGame.build/Objects-normal/i386/SquirrelGameAppDelegate.o collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: Duplicate: [Duplicate Symbol Error in Objective-C build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264455/duplicate-symbol-error-in-objective-c-build)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say exactly without code, so please post canVirate definition.
Usually that error means that canVirate is global variable defined in header file. Compiler creates the variable in every module that includes the header. You should declare canVirate in header, but define it in SomeModule.m file:

SomeModule.h:

```
extern int canVirate;
```

SomeModule.m:

```
int canVirate = 123;
```