# iPhone SDK - duplicate symbol error? How do I fix this?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, error-log

**Error log**

> Build test of project test with configuration Debug
>
> Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app/test normal i386 cd
>   "/Users/justine/Desktop/test - iPhone/test" setenv
>   MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6 setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   -arch i386 -isysroot
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
>   "-L/Users/justine/Desktop/test -
>   iPhone/test/build/Debug-iphonesimulator"
>   "-F/Users/justine/Desktop/test -
>   iPhone/test/build/Debug-iphonesimulator" -filelist
>   "/Users/justine/Desktop/test -
>   iPhone/test/build/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/i386/test.LinkFileList"
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2
>   -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics
>   -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework
>   SystemConfiguration -lz.1.2.3 -o "/Users/justine/Desktop/test -
>   iPhone/test/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app/test"
>
> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_ASIAuthenticationDialog.request in
>   /Users/justine/Desktop/test -
>   iPhone/test/build/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIAuthenticationDialog-F3DE19D52DB79A72.o
>   and /Users/justine/Desktop/test -
>   iPhone/test/build/test.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.build/Objects-normal/i386/ASIAuthenticationDialog-6A37D8A080A72C67.o
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Comment: oops! found the issue, duplicated asiauthenticationdialog.m file!

Comment: Duplicate: [Duplicate Symbol Error in Objective-C build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264455/duplicate-symbol-error-in-objective-c-build)

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have a duplicated file:

```
ld: duplicate symbol ..........
```

For what i see its called ASIAuthenticationDialog.
Check for that one.