# IOS Linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

> duplicate symbol _a in:
>       /Users/pgmutti/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPhoneXMPP-dzzpetgrkxvjlwfavatmfkvovusv/Build/Intermediates/iPhoneXMPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhoneXMPP.build/Objects-normal/i386/SettingsViewController.o
>       /Users/pgmutti/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPhoneXMPP-dzzpetgrkxvjlwfavatmfkvovusv/Build/Intermediates/iPhoneXMPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iPhoneXMPP.build/Objects-normal/i386/AddDamageAccount.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have already removed the image reference which I had used in both the classes.. But still I am getting this error.. How to fix it..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264455/iphone-duplicate-symbol-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have 2 copies of following files in different different groups of your project :

**AddDamageAccount**

**SettingsViewController**

Please confirm  !

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. Pls give me a min let me confirm

Comment: Ya.. One is the back up copy and another one is the current copy which I work on.. The back up is saved in PGM folder and the current project is saved on PG folder.. Both on desktop

Comment: @ghorpade.naveen please use one copy, otherwise xcode will keep giving error

Comment: shall I delete the back up??

Comment: @ghorpade.naveen Make sure, it do not disturbs your project. I just want you to have one copy of each and every file. That's it !

Comment: Backup? Why don't you use version control?

Comment: actually I use the svn but for safer side i use again back on the mac book.. :)