# Linker failed with error code 1

Tags: ios, constants

I keep getting the error `Linker command failed with exit code 1` and it seems to be because of my `.h-file`. In my `stringsDE.h` I define constant strings. Might this be the problem?

> duplicate symbol _QUESTIONCATBUTTONMIXED in:
>       /Users/philip_air/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/juraQuiz-awgytksreajdjbdmoctjoffmzmmk/Build/Intermediates/juraQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/juraQuiz.build/Objects-normal/armv7/appLaunch.o
>       /Users/philip_air/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/juraQuiz-awgytksreajdjbdmoctjoffmzmmk/Build/Intermediates/juraQuiz.build/Debug-iphoneos/juraQuiz.build/Objects-normal/armv7/quizVC.o
>   ld: 17 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

CODE:

http://pastebin.com/iGTVAb6K

Comment: you may be initalized this QUESTIONCATBUTTONMIXED variable in some other place other than constants file. change the variable name in other places except constants file and build application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare all of your strings in your .h file using:

```
// QUESTIONCAT BUTTONS
extern NSString const *QUESTIONCATBUTTON1;
extern NSString const *QUESTIONCATBUTTON2;
extern NSString const *QUESTIONCATBUTTON3;
extern NSString const *QUESTIONCATBUTTONMIXED;
```

and then truly define them *in one single .m file* like this:

```
// QUESTIONCAT BUTTONS
NSString * const QUESTIONCATBUTTON1 = @"Zivilrecht";
NSString * const QUESTIONCATBUTTON2 = @"öffentliches Recht";
NSString * const QUESTIONCATBUTTON3 = @"Strafrecht";
NSString * const QUESTIONCATBUTTONMIXED = @"Gemischt";
```

Comment: yes yes, I'm importing it into all my views! In my stringsDE.h I save all the strings I need to use in my program, so I don't have to hardcode them. Is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: Just try adding the above code to the very top and bottom of your .h file and see if things get better for you.

Comment: I found this: `also had this problem by declaring a const * NSString in the header file (incorrectly) instead of the implementation file (correctly)`. This means I can't define consts in an `.h-File` to include it everywhere?

Comment: maybe you should edit your question to show how you are declaring your strings in your .h file?

Comment: do I have to use #ifndef in .m-File too?

Comment: it works. but thats kind of a weird solution, isn't it? I'd prefer to have only one file.

Comment: You have a single .h file that you include anywhere you want those constant strings to be used, and a single .m file that actually defines the contents of those constant strings.

Comment: yes but I have to type the string name twice. in my .h and in my .m

Comment: You could also use "`#define`" in your .h files (which would allow you to ditch the .m), but [that's not optimal for the compiler](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/116304-const-nsstring-vs-extern-vs-define-for-global-constants.html)

Comment: so the only way having one .h-File I would have to make them non-const?

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this before it could be you are #importing a .m file instead of a .h.

Comment: Well i don't think constant strings are the problem try commenting them out and see if it builds real quick

Comment: they might be, I comment them out, and I commented out every line where I used them. error gone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264455/iphone-duplicate-symbol-error  possibly this?

Comment: yeah but how shall I define constant strings that i want to use in more than one file?

Comment: can you show me more code how are you defining.  Also you could have one file with a class method returning the string so you could always just call [NEEDSTRING MYSTRING]; and you would get it.

Comment: I put a link in my post. I want to keep it simple though. I don't think I need a class for that

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LJciFZaJ  This is what I would do.  Does not make it over complicate or anything.  Basically if you want to use it #import "strings.h"  then you just do [strings GET_QUESTIONS_URL]; and it will return the string.

Comment: thanks! great solution, but I don't want to use a class for that. I don't see, why my solution won't work