# build error duplicate symbols arclite.o

Tags: xcode, linker, arm64

I am trying to build my Xcode project, but I recieve the error displayed below. Please help me to solve this error, thank you in advance.

```
duplicate symbol __non_lazy_classes in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a(arclite.o)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a(arclite.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$___ARCLite__ in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.10.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a(arclite.o)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a(arclite.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue compiling on iOS 10. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: any news? I'm experiencing the same right now

Comment: same issue, I opened the project in Xcode 8 beta and then on Xcode 7.2 :(:(

Answer (score 0):

Removing one of the libraries you passed to linker can solve this issue.