# duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

When i run on xcode 7 i got this error :

```
"duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FlurryPLCrashReportMachExceptionInfo duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Check if there are duplicate @implementation FlurryPLCrashReportMachExceptionInfo

Comment: see this http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/flurry-and-appodeal-integration-conflict/24918

Comment: Checked for  duplication class in Comple Sources(Xcode) but not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone: Duplicate Symbol Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264455/iphone-duplicate-symbol-error)

Answer (score 1):

If you added `flurry` without **CocoaPods** you need choose your **Target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources** and find `FlurryPLCrashReportMachExceptionInfo` class.

Remove duplicates